# Big thanks to the Blender.SE community!

Tags: discussion

Moderators, veterans and other mentors.
Before any more of you leave, you need to know:

### YOU'RE AWESOME!

*(it doesn't get said enough)*

It's just amazing to be a part of such a great community.
Blender SE is the first site I check in the morning. And the last one I check before going to bed.
I learn so much here every day, I can hardly put it into words.
People here restored my faith in humanity.
And also, helped me to find a purpose (*don't laugh, you'll hurt my ego*).

So, *mighty moderators* and *common folk :)*, veterans and newbies:

- Thank you for helping others.
- Thank you for being kind to people with silly questions.
- Thank you for your infinite patience with me and other newbies.
- Thank you for going out of your way to help solve somebody else's problems.
- Thank you.

---

Duarte Farrajota Ramos - Man, I don't know how you do it. Every single day. Respect.
Cegaton - if you ever read this, just know that you left a mark. You're my hero.
Robert Gützkow - you really know Blender inside out. Damn.
Robin Betts - you always come up with even more elegant solution to any problem. Like, how?
gandalf - legendary. I read 600 of your answers so far. Took me 4 months. Worth it.
batFINGER - I don't speak Python, but now I really really want to.

*(I just don't know where else to post this)*

*Still. Cegaton? Really?*

Comment: Awww, thank you! I wouldn't say that I know Blender inside out, but I try my best. Blender's source code is simply too big to know everything. I love helping the community and I'm very glad that my contributions have made a positive impact, even if it's just a little bit.

Comment: I'm so glad the message got across :). I certainly benefit a lot from all your answers (old and new) and wish there were more people like you on the web :).

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ thanks for this. I'll let cegaton know about this post. I hope BSE stays strong in spite of our departure. Kind of sad that this kind of thing is the only time we all think to say thank you.

Comment: @David Thanks for passing it along. I had this post in my head for a few weeks, but decided to hurry up :). You never heard of me, but your [extensive Q&A posts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26108/78972) are of great help anytime I'm lost. Enjoy your retirement, and make sure to check on us every once in a while :).